# Mock suspend that never returns

Tags: mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to mock a suspend function to never return any result. Analogous to this would be usage of `Single.never()`.

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by never returning? Suspend forever? Always throw an exception?

Answer (score 6):

My team achieved that with a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` that never calls `resume()`. Something like this:

```
suspend fun never(): Nothing = suspendCancellableCoroutine { }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mockk I did the following. Be sure to switch to a non-test dispatcher so the delay is not skipped.

```
coEvery { mockApi.getEmployees() } coAnswers {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { delay(Long.MAX_VALUE) }
    Success
}
```